# How to writea file in %APPDATA% folder python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I'm trying to write a file in %appdata% but when I run the code I get this error:

```
    with open(os.path.join(key_dir+ "\\key_capture.txt")) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\George Mauricio\\AppData\\Local\\key_capture.txt'
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from os import path

#there are some in between

def write_file(keys):
    with open(os.path.join(key_dir+ "\\key_capture.txt")) as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            Key.space
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

1). You are opening file in a wrong way.
2). The Correct way is given below.

```
with open(os.path.join(key_dir,  "key_capture.txt")) as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open it in 'a' mode. The file is created if it does not exist.

use   `with open(os.path.join(key_dir, "key_capture.txt"),'a') as f:`
instead of with `open(os.path.join(key_dir, "key_capture.txt")) as f:`

Comment: I tried both suggestions and I'm still getting errors

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\George Mauricio\\AppData\\Local\\key_capture.txt\\a'

Comment: please try by assigning the path like  C:/Users/George Mauricio/AppData/Local/key_capture.txt

Comment: I know it would solve the problem for me, but I'd like to replace my own username with user's username. So the code would run in other computers.

Comment: have you tried by using it ?   key_dir+"/" + "key_capture.txt"